# Parse json in init, using Decodable protocol

Tags: json, swift, swift4, decodable

I would like to parse json file in init of my model. I want it to take URL and initialize all stored properties. Like:

`init(from url: URL) { ... }`,

so the question is how do I do it? I tried to do it this way:

`let info = try JSONDecoder().decode(Model.self, from: data)`,

but it just creates a new object and seems like a bad decision.

Thanks.

Comment: self = try JSONDecoder...

Comment: Btw your init would need to throw and better to use data instead of url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a codable struct with the kind of init you want :

```
struct NameObject: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
    }

    init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }

    init(withData data: Data) {
        do {
            self = try JSONDecoder().decode(NameObject.self, from: data)
        } catch {
            self.id = 0
            self.name = "unknown"
            // error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the do try catch and make your init throw. Creating an useless object doesn’t make any sense

Comment: Btw why would you catch the error if you won’t use it. Better to make a fallible initializer

Comment: I wasn't thinking how to write the best init possible, just how to solve OP problem. BTW you can edit my answer if you want ;)